# В двух почти одинаковых кодах разные результаты в выходе

Tags: python

Первый:

```
def f(x, y, a):
    return ((x - 30 < a) and (15 - y < a)) or (x * (y + 3) > 60)

for a in range(1, 1001):
    fl = True
    for x in range(1, 1001):
        for y in range(1, 1001):
            if not( f(x, y, a) ):
                fl = False
                break
        if not(fl):
            break
    if fl:
        print(a)
        break
```

Второй:

```
def f(x, y, a):
    return ((x - 30 < a) and (15 - y < a)) or (x * (y + 3) > 60)

for a in range(1001):
    fl = True
    for x in range(1001):
        for y in range(1001):
            if not( f(x, y, a) ):
                fl = False
                break
        if not(fl):
            break
    if fl:
        print(a)
        break
```

Разница лишь в range(), но в первом случае выход равен 15, а во втором 16.

Comment: В чем вопрос-то? Ну, коды почти одинаковы, и результаты почти одинаковы. А почему разные коды должны давать одинаковый результат?

Comment: коды у вас одинаковые. у вас данные разные.

Comment: `range(1, 1001)` и `range(1001)` разные, т.к., по умолчанию, первое значение 0

Comment: Что в первом случае x и y принимают значения 15 и 16, что и во втором, но тогда почему этот ноль, значение которого принимает x y только во втором случае играет роль? Безумно извиняюсь если я жестко туплю

Answer (score 1):

Разница тут:

```py
print(f(1, 1, 15))
print(f(0, 0, 15))
```

Вывод:

```
True
False
```

Циклы, проходящие `x` и `y` от `1` выполняются целиком уже на `a = 15` и алгоритм заканчивается, а вот циклы, начинающиеся с `0`, на `a = 15` прерываются досрочно из-за `f(0, 0, 15) == False` и выполняются успешно до конца только при `a = 16`.